# hibernate JPA problems when updating entity's set of child references (OneToMany)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Content {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "content_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "identifier", sequenceName = "contents_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "identifier")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade({
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "content_id", nullable = false)
    private Set<Provider> providers;

    public Set<Provider> getProviders() {
        if (providers == null) {
            providers = new HashSet<>();
        }
        return providers;
    }

    protected void setProviders(Set<Provider> providers) {
        this.providers = providers;
    }
}

public class Provider {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "provider_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "identifier", sequenceName = "contents_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "identifier")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "content_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long contentId;
}
```

I have 2 scenarios:

1. To create a new Content
   In short I am doing the following:

   Content content = new Content();
   Set providers = new HashSet()<>; // fill the set
   content.getProviders().addAll(providers);

Then I am using a wrapper for *io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO*
and I am running:

```
content = persist(content);
```

Here everything works well, when I get back the entity content
I can see that it contains the Set of providers and each provider **has an ID**

2. In my second scenario I am trying to update the existing content:

   Content content = findById(id);
   content.getProviders().clear();
   content.getProviders().add(new Provider()); // I am adding a new provider
   content = persist(content);

The problem is that in the second case (the update) I see that now the entity has only the new provider, but for some reason the **provider ID is returned as null**.

```
content.getProviders().iterator().next().getId(); // returns null
```

Only after again I am getting this content I can see the id that was given to the new provider:

```
Content content = findById(id);
content.getProviders().iterator().next().getId(); // returns an id and not null
```

Can someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? I am using the exact same persist in both cases that according to the documentation should create if the entity is new or update in case the entity already exists.

I would like to note that I have shortened here, I am basically see this behavior when I am generating a DTO object and returns it to the client as JSON.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your second scenario, do you see the provider id *in the database* once you save the content? May be some other process update the `provider` when you fetch it next time ? And also not clear what wrapper DAO is doing, is it just a wrapper around entity manager or doing something more than that?

Comment: Hi, I can see that it is still not updated in the DB, only when the transaction is completed, it is going back to the resource tier (rest API using dropwizard) and only after the execution is completed I can see the change in the DB. Why is it different between the create and the update? they use exactly the same persist method. Regarding the DAO wrapper, it is just another abstract class the extends hibernate's AbstractDAO and adds some more easier functionality, nothing really special. Thank you

Comment: I would also like to note that I am not using entity manager but rather the AbstractDAO uses SessionFactory